# select group data and order data from low to high

Tags: php, mysql, sql

having data in table `tbltest` like bellow

```
    +---------------+--------------+
    | customfieldid | fieldvalue   |
    +---------------+--------------+
    |             1 | 3            |
    |             1 | 7            |
    |             3 | 5            |
    |             3 | 1            |
    |             4 | 5            |
    +---------------+--------------+
```

i want select data from this table and group by `customfieldid` order by `fieldvalue asc`

Comment: `SELECT customerfieldid, fieldvalue FROM tbltest GROUP BY customfieldid ORDER BY fieldvalue ASC;`

Comment: Have you tried anything from your side to achieve your goal???

Comment: 'group by customfieldid order by fieldvalue asc' makes no sense in this context. What would the desired result look like

Comment: what is the desired out put..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want first order by  than group by :-

```
Select * From
(SELECT customerfieldid, fieldvalue FROM tbltest
ORDER BY fieldvalue ASC ) new 
GROUP BY new.customefieldid
```

or if you want first group by  than order by :-

```
SELECT `customerfieldid`, `fieldvalue`
FROM `tbltest` 
GROUP BY `customfieldid` 
ORDER BY `fieldvalue` ASC
```